# javascript acces an item of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pixi.js

I'm a beginner with javascript used with PIXI.

I don't know how to format an array with row and line. I try this snippet but when i want to access a specific value of this array :

```js
alert(graphics[2][1].position.x)
```

I have this error  :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined(anonymous function) @ main.js:40`

Here my complete snippet :

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600,{backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var container = new PIXI.Container()
stage.addChild(container);

for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
      graphics.beginFill(0xFF3300);
      graphics.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);
      graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
      graphics.position.x= 40 * i;
      graphics.position.y=40 * j;
      container.addChild(graphics);
    };
};
alert(graphics[2][1].position.x)//here my error
container.x=100
container.y=100
container.scale.x=container.scale.y=.1;
animate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    container.rotation += .1;
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

Comment: `graphics` seems to be an object. Why do you try to use it as an array?

Comment: As a beginner you should really learn the basics.

Comment: `graphics.name=i,j`. I wonder what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I want simply know the position.x of the item [2][1] is it not possible with javascript ?

Comment: There's nothing to do with js. You don't understand what you are looking for, so I vote to close

Comment: ??? i don't understand i specify that i'm a beginner you could be more indulgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 2d array then you need to use this code:

```
var graphics = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    graphics[j] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        graphics[j][i] = new PIXI.Graphics();

        graphics[j][i].beginFill(0xFF3300);
        graphics[j][i].lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);
        graphics[j][i].drawRect(0,0,10,10);
        graphics[j][i].position.x = 40 * i;
        graphics[j][i].position.y = 40 * j;
        container.addChild(graphics[j][i]);
    };
};
```

then you will be able to call this:

```
alert(graphics[2][1].position.x);
```